# jquery load not loading another page div that is populated dynamically

Tags: jquery, html

my    index.html     looks like this:

```
<div id="content"></div>

<script>$("#content").load("another_page.html #main"); </script>
```

another_page.html look like this:

```
 <div id="main">loading</div>

<script>$('#main').text('main should change');</script>
```

every thing works fine except that  when in index.html,  it is showing "loading" instead of "main should change"

Comment: When you load this HTML file, it's not being executed. You're getting the raw HTML.

Comment: yea ..i get "loading" and that shows that it loaded but it is like the load() did not wait for #main to be populated with "main should change"

Comment: This is expected behaviour. JS in the loaded page is not executed. If you want this to work you will need to update the text of `#main` in the callback of the AJAX request made from the first page.

Comment: @McCrossan please , kindly show me how?

Answer (score 1):

From the `jQuery` [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/) for v3 `.load()` `$("#content").load("another_page.html");` will successfully load JavaScript with the page but for (note `#main`)

```
$("#content").load("another_page.html #main");
```

script blocks in the document being loaded into `#content` are stripped out and not executed.

To get around this, you could call:

```
$("#content").load("another_page.html #main", function () {
    $('#main').text('main should change');
});
```

(and remove the script block from `another_page.html`) and the script will run when the secondary page is loaded.

Comment: the problem is that "main should change" can be anything ( it is dynamic )

Comment: You could put the value in a hidden div in `another_page.html` and then `$('#main').text($('#hidden-div').text());`